# prismic preview not displaying updated content in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, headless, prismic.io

I'm developing site with Gatsby and Prismic.
I am implementing prismic preview with prismic-javascript. When click the preview on prismic, gatsby redirecting it to the proper URL but updated content not displaying now.

I tried to use the gatsby-source-prismic-preview plugin but it not worked.

```
const Preview = ({ history, location }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const params = qs.parse(location.search.slice(1))
    if (!params.token) {
      return console.warn(`No token available, check your configuration`)
    }

    client.previewSession(params.token, linkResolver, '/')
      .then(url => {
        navigate(url);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
  return null
}
```

This is my preview page.

Please let me what is my mistake.

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/prismicio/prismic-gatsby/blob/main/packages/gatsby-plugin-prismic-previews/docs/migrating-from-gatsby-source-prismic.md ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `gatsby-source-prismic-preview` but I'm not sure it's really up to date anymore.
You should take a look at `https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql`, It's the official plugin developed by the same guy that does `gatsby-source-prismic-preview` and it's backed up by the Prismic team.
Maybe open an issue on GitHub if you don't feel like migrating to the new one.

Comment: Did you implement prismic preview before with `gatsby-source-prismic-graphql`?

Comment: Also is it possible to use in production mode?